# How do you download Coverity Static Code Analyzer issues as a text, CSV, or external file?

Tags: coverity

I am using the Coverity tool to analyze my code for possible issues. I was wondering if there was a way to extract the results from Coverity into a text/csv/external file.

Comment: You can use coverity REST API to extract results. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823941/8059154 for details

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're running analysis on your own PC (e.g. have Coverity locally installed) or over the web as in [Open Source version](https://scan.coverity.com/projects/).

- In the first case, in "Intermediate" directory, there is **Intermediate/output/preview-report.json** file with some analysis details. This could be parsed by a tool of your choice (e.g. Python script)
- For the second case i wouldn't have a clue.