# Does Coverity have Rest API

Tags: coverity

I want to store results from [Coverity®](http://www.coverity.com/) to InfluxDB and I was wondering does Coverity have REST API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're only trying to dump data to InfluxDB, you can curl data from REST API and insert resulting json to the database. I do something similar, but in CSV format.

1. Create a view in coverity 'Issues: By Snapshot' that contains all your defects.
2. Curl data from coverity view

   ```
   json format
   curl --user <userid>:<password> 
   "http://<coverity_url>/api/viewContents/issues/v1/<View Name>?projectId=<project ID>&rowCount=-1"

   csv format
   curl --header "Accept: text/csv" --user <userid>:<password> 
   "http://<coverity_url>/api/viewContents/issues/v1/<View Name>?projectId=<project ID>&rowCount=-1"
   ```

Example:
If you created a view 'My Defects' in project 'My Project' the command would be

```
curl --user <userid>:<password> "http://<coverity_url>/api/viewContents/issues/v1/My%20Defects?projectId=My%20Project&rowCount=-1"
```

In above URL:

%20 -- URL encoded space

rowcount=-1 -- Download all rows in view. You can set it to desired limit.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no.

There is a very limited REST api but it only covers a few very specific things.  I'd recommend you use `cov-manage-im` where you can and only use the SOAP API if you need something more.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on the use of `cov-manage-im` @Mark

Answer (score 1):

`cov-manage-im` can help, it can be used to retrive defects for specific projects and streams. `cov-manage-im --help` can give you more info

```
cov-manage-im --host youcovhostname --user yourusername --password yourpassword --mode defects --show --project yourprojectname
```